# gatling - Saved whole response data in previous API call but how to Extract value from response variable in next API call

Tags: scala, gatling, jsonpath

In Gatling using scala scripting.. I need to extract choiceId's for each question according to the questionTypes and questionId's from the previous response and submit one choice randomly in the next API call.

```
From an API_01 of the response I am saving the questionTypes, questionId's and also saving the whole response data in Resp using json path.
Now according using he no. of question ID's which is an array the loop iterates (if 4 question Id's then there are 4 question types and ll iterate 4 times) and also checks the question type for each iteration and switch is used to perform the function according to the question type.
After going inside the question type I need to answer for which I need ChoiceId's which will differ from question to question (which will have 3 choices or 2 choices or 5 choices)
So I have saved the whole response in the previous API_01 call now I need to extract it and add to API_02 call POST request json file; I have QuestionId and QuestionType
```

API_01 to get the questionID, questionType and ChoiceID

```
private val Assessment = exec(http("assessment")
    .post("/Test-graphql")
    .headers(commonHeaders)
    .body(ElFileBody("/createAssessment.json"))
    .check(jsonPath("""$.data.assessment.items[*].question.id""").findAll.saveAs("questionIds"))
    .check(jsonPath("""$.data.assessment.items[*].question.type""").findAll.saveAs("questionType"))
    .check(jsonPath("""$.data.assessment""").findAll.saveAs("ResponseData"))
  )
```

Response of Above API Call

```
 {
  "data": {
  "assessment": {
  "id": "sample01",
  "items": [
    {
      "question": {
        "id": "sample02",
        "code": "E_01",
        "version": 1,
        "type": "MULTIPLE_SELECTION",
        "language": "E",
        "body": {
          "choices": {
            "minChoice": 1,
            "maxChoice": 7,
            "choiceItems": [

              {
                "choiceId": 2, --> How to get these choiceID for answer Submission
              },
              {
                "choiceId": 3, --> How to get these choiceID 
              },
              {
                "choiceId": 115, --> How to get these choiceID 
              },
              {
                "choiceId": 196, --> How to get these choiceID 
              }
            ]
          },
        },
      },
      "submissions": [

      ],
    }, 

{
      "question": {
        "id": "sample02",
        "code": "E_01",
        "version": 1,
        "type": "FILL_IN_THE_BLANK",
        "language": "E",
        "body": {
          "choices": {
            "minChoice": 1,
            "maxChoice": 7,
            "choiceItems": [

              {
                "choiceId": 20,  --> How to get these choiceID 
              },
              {
                "choiceId": 15,
              },
              {
                "choiceId": 11,
              },
              {
                "choiceId": 156,
              }
            ]
          },
        },
      },
      "submissions": [

      ],
    }

    ]
} } }
```

Method during Answer submission:

```
 private val Answers = foreach("${questionId}", "id","i") {

    doSwitch("${questionTypes(i)}")(
      "MULTIPLE_CHOICE" -> answerMCQ,
      "MULTIPLE_SELECTION" -> answerMSQ
      "FILL_IN_THE_BLANK" -> answerFIB
    )
```

Sample Answer Function

```
private val answerFIB = exec(
        http("Submit Answer")
          .post("/submitanswer-grapql")
          .headers(commonHeaders)
          .body(ElFileBody("data/AnswerFIB.json"))
          .check(status.is(200))
          .check(jsonPath("$.data.assessmentAnswerSubmit.id").is("${assessmentId}"))
)
```

Sample AnswerFIB.json for answer submission:

```
    "answer": {
        "ChoiceId": 354,--> Here I need to provide Choice ID which changes for each question answer
        "answer": "Sample01",
        "type": "FILL_IN_THE_BLANK"
    }
```

Comment: can you share some more of your code? particularly the request with the checks and then various answer functions?

Comment: I have provided the requested data. I need the ChoiceId's wen I submit the answers which in API_02 request body

Comment: are you looking to submit a random choice id (of those returned for that question)? Or are you looking to make one request for each choice

Comment: I only need one choice id for submitting answers and need to select it randomly from the choice ID's listed in the response.. Eg:- if  choice Id's - 2,3, 115, 196. I need to select any one of these